# How to know if powershell is installed on remote workstation?

Tags: powershell, installation, remote-desktop

How to know if powershell is installed on **remote workstation**; we need to do the inventory of all the powershell enabled workstations so that we can plan a change for deploying; is there a way to remotely know if powershell is installed and what version?

Comment: what OS are you running on the clients? xp? vista? Windows7 has powershell 2.0 installed by default.

Comment: Got interested in having a function like this myself, so I updated my answer with a new powershell-version if you need it. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check if file exist ?

```
$path= "\\remote\C$\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
if(test-path $path){(ls $path).VersionInfo}
```

Comment: If i am checking for wither powershell 2.0 or 3.0 , the path should be $path= "\\remote\C$\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v2.0\powershell.exe" or $path= "\\remote\C$\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v3.0\powershell.exe" ?

Comment: no. microsoft forgot to change the number, so all versions reside in the v1.0 folder

Comment: This is my output Product Version is 6.2.8370.0 and FileVersion is 6.2.8370.0 (winmain_win8rc.120428-1335) how to determine if its version 2.0 or 3.0 or even 1.0?

Comment: `6.0*` is PS1.0, `6.1*` is PS2.0 and `6.2*` is PS3

Comment: @Graimer - on Server 2008 with PS v2, I'm seeing exe ProductVersion 6.0.6002.18111

Comment: Hmm, weird. On `c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe`? I must admit I didn't test it on vista/2008, only 7, 2008r2(ps2.0 is default) and 8/2012.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a batch-script that you run manually or try using GPO(as a startup script). It will save a file `my-computer-name.txt` with "false" if powershell wasn't found or the PS-version(1.0 or 2.0) if PS is installed. Then you'd just read the files.

pscheck.bat

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1" /v Install ^| FIND "Install"') DO SET PowerShellInstalled=%%A

IF NOT "%PowerShellInstalled%"=="0x1" (
echo false > \\remote\location\%COMPUTERNAME%.txt

GOTO end
)

FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellEngine" /v PowerShellVersion ^| FIND "PowerShellVersion"') DO SET PowerShellVersion=%%A

echo %PowerShellVersion% > \\remote\location\%COMPUTERNAME%.txt

:end
```

The PSversion value for 3.0 in the registry is in another key(...\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine), but I'm gussing PS3.0 is not necessary to know since it's so new and all PS scripts work with PS 2.0.

**Update:** Powershell version

```
function Check-PS {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [String[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

    Process
    {
        foreach ($computer in $ComputerName) 
        {

            $path = "\\$computer\C$\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
            $exists = $false

            #Check if exists
            if(Test-Path $path){
                $exists = $true
                #Detect version
                switch -Wildcard ((Get-ChildItem $path).VersionInfo.ProductVersion)
                {
                    "6.0*" { $ver = 1 }
                    "6.1*" { $ver = 2 }
                    "6.2*" { $ver = 3 }
                    default { $ver = 0 }
                }

            } else {
                Write-Error "Failed to connect to $computer"
                $ver = -1
            }

            #Return object
            New-Object pscustomobject -Property @{
                Computer = $computer
                HasPowerShell = $exists
                Version = $ver
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It supports mulitple computernames and input via pipeline.

```
Check-PS -ComputerName "Computer1", "Computer2"
```

Or

```
"Computer1", "Computer2" | Check-PS
```

Test with localcomputer(default computername):

```
PS > Check-PS

HasPowerShell Computer Version
------------- -------- -------
         True FRODE-PC       3
```

Comment: Thanks for the script, one of our domains is using exclusively XP workstations dated back to 2004 , so need to know powershell enabled ones.